# Spring GetMapping regex expression

Tags: java, regex, spring, spring-boot

We are trying to write a GetMapping in the Spring application, but it's not working as required. Below is the my code:

```
@RequestMapping("/app")
public class UserController {
    @GetMapping("/embed/{numericId:^((?!e=.*).)*$}")
    public String sendEmbedRedirect() {
      //Code
    }
}
```

So as per above code I am trying to allow and reject below type of URL:

```
Allowed: http://localhost:9001/app/embed/external/517331346b7357374a4b415038305770743555636c30516d2532466f464b2532467944356b4c4c6a7666306f385a51253344/a_p__Got&a_f__true/param_1

Not Allowed: http://localhost:9001/app/embed/external/517331346b7357374a4b415038305770743555636c30516d2532466f464b2532467944356b4c4c6a7666306f385a51253344/a_p__Got&a_f__true?e=L90
```

So as per above example only URL which does not contain "e" parameter should be allowed and URL with "e" parameter should be rejected.

Allowed link is accessed and interrupted by back-end.

Not Allowed link is accessed by Front-end directly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing your path variable "/embed/{numericId}/{apSomething}" with an optional parameter (/the/path?optionalParam).

```
handleRequest(
   @PathVariable String numericId,
   @PathVariable String apSomething,
   @RequestParam(value = "e", required = false) Boolean e
) {
  if(e!=null) {
     "return 400;?"
  }
  . . .
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I don't want it to come inside method else it will become circular loop, not allowed url should not be ignored it has some other use.

Comment: Also URl is correct it is not mixing path variable and query string parameter URL is generated in such a way only.